# How to convert Javascript code to human-readable opcodes or asm?

Tags: javascript, v8, spidermonkey

As far as I know, Javascript code can either result in `JS bytecode` or `asm` instructions (if the internal JIT-compiler was able to convert the code directly to machine instructions).

Is there any way to convert Javascript code to human-readable JS byte code (or asm instructions) - depending on how the V8 engine converts it?

Answer (score 5):

You can run d8 or node with `--print-bytecode --print-opt-code` to print both bytecode and optimized assembly code to stdout when it is generated. You can use `--print-bytecode-filter=foo` and `--print-opt-code-filter=foo` if you're only interested in function `foo`. You will need a debug build, or a release build with `v8_enable_disassembler = true` in its `args.gn` (regular release builds don't include the disassembler code in order to save binary size). Optimized code will be generated when a function is "hot", i.e. has spent some time running.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bytenode from npm to create an executable for your node app. If you want to read the executable you might use tools like objdump, strace, radare2. You can also open the executable in vim and use the option :%!xxd to get a more human friendly view.

Comment: Thanks! Can you elaborate how to use `:%!xxd `? Like in vim after opening a binary?

Comment: I don't think bytenode can ever pack optimized code. Binaries created this way will contain bytecode, but non-V8-specific tools like objdump probably don't know what to do with that.