# How to view the assembly code generated from my JavaScript (in Chrome)?

Tags: javascript, assembly, browser, v8, disassembly

Is it possible to view the machine code (x86 instructions) that a browser ultimately generates from my JavaScript? E.g.

```
--- Raw source ---
function add(a, b){
  return a + b;
}
...

--- Code ---
source_position = 0
kind = FUNCTION
Instructions (size = 456)
0x36953100     0  8b4c2404       mov ecx,[esp+0x4]
0x36953104     4  81f991806049   cmp ecx,0x49608091          ;; object: 0x49608091 <undefined>
0x3695310a    10  750a           jnz 22  (0x36953116)
0x3695310c    12  8b4e13         mov ecx,[esi+0x13]
0x3695310f    15  8b4917         mov ecx,[ecx+0x17]
0x36953112    18  894c2404       mov [esp+0x4],ecx
0x36953116    22  55             push ebp
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert Javascript code to human-readable opcodes or asm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58229838/how-to-convert-javascript-code-to-human-readable-opcodes-or-asm)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your script isn't transformed to machine code directly. Chrome and Node.js run JavaScript on a virtual machine called V8 and you can get the VM bytecode using:

```bash
node --print-bytecode script.js
```

Then V8 executes and optimizes the bytecode and calls external C libraries and OS API (system calls) or Web API. Final machine code may vary even with the same JavaScript code (for example before and after optimization).

You can also start Chrome from the command line with
`--js-flags="--print-bytecode"`

**UPD:**

As @PeterCordes noticed Node.js allows seeing the Turbofan generated machine code using

```bash
node --print-opt-code script.js
```

Chrome:

```bash
--js-flags="--print-opt-code"
```

Also you can use an HTML visualizer like https://github.com/v8/v8/tree/main/tools/turbolizer

Comment: The OP doesn't want to just look at the bytecode, they want the actual optimized machine code that eventually gets JITed after inlining and profile-guided optimization.  That's what really matters for final performance.  (This answer is somewhat useful for the related question of looking at bytecode, but doesn't answer the real question.)

Comment: @PeterCordes i want to say OP can't see final machine code

Comment: Probably not in a browser, but it's possible in node.js.  [get assembly code generated by JavaScript compiler](//stackoverflow.com/q/47242488)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I learned something new and updated my answer :) Anyway OP use browser environment :(

Comment: Also https://github.com/v8/v8/tree/master/tools/turbolizer is a tool for seeing various stages of optimization, including final asm.  Again, probably not usable in a browser, but running the same thing in node.js might give similar results to v8 in chrome, if the code isn't too dependent on browser-specific APIs for displaying things.

Comment: Hi there, the command `node --print-opt-code script.js` doesn't print the machine code like it does with the `--print-bytecode` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Run your code with Node.js (which uses [the same JavaScript engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_(JavaScript_engine)) as Chrome) with the `--trace-turbo` flag, like this:

```bash
node --trace-turbo <( echo "for (let i = 100000; i>0; i--) {}")
```

it will generate some turbo-<whatever>.cfg files and a turbo-<foo>.json file. Next, go to Turbolizer:

https://v8.github.io/tools/head/turbolizer/index.html

press ctrl-l and upload the .json file. It will show you the generated bytecode, the resulting assembly and a graph. The top-middle dropdown selects various stages of optimization, you probably want the last one.

[image: A screenshot of Turbolize with the above code]

You can see the decrement instruction at address 5c (I ran this on an ARM CPU):

```
subs w3, w3, #0x1 (1)
```